# Needn't I to write extra code when I use "built-in support for two-way data binding"?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I have read the artical https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

The platform provides built-in support for two-way data binding when you use the attributes in the following table, please see Image A.

A：If I use built-in support such as android:text for two-way data binding, what I need write is only `android:text="@={viewmodel.myContent}"`, right?

B: I needn't write BaseObservable when I use built-in two-way data binding support, right?

C: I needn't write code to be careful not to introduce infinite loops when I use built-in two-way data binding support, right?

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> If I use built-in support such as android:text for two-way data
> binding, what I need write is only
> android:text="@={viewmodel.myContent}", right?

Yes, there is no need for any observable implementation. Here's an example from my github room-database (with `note` object) project

- [AddNoteViewModel](https://github.com/Pavneet-Sing/room-demo-repo/blob/master/room-demo-kotlin-mvvm-dagger/src/main/java/com/example/pavneet_singh/room_demo_kotin_mvvm_dagger/viewmodels/AddNoteViewModel.kt)
- [activity_add_note.xml](https://github.com/Pavneet-Sing/room-demo-repo/blob/master/room-demo-kotlin-mvvm-dagger/src/main/res/layout/activity_add_note.xml)

> I needn't write BaseObservable when I use built-in two-way data
> binding support, right?

Yes, The corresponding binding adapter(with generated code) will take care of this.

> I needn't write code to be careful not to introduce infinite loops
> when I use built-in two-way data binding support, right?

Yes, Binding Adapter takes care of validating the input for duplicates to avoid infinite loops.